# What is term for parked an IP address?

Tags: dns, ip, ip-address, domain-name

I had a website at http://berkelilingkesemua.info/ and I also had a specifically IP address for visitors like this http://74.82.164.10/ and what is term for that ?.

How could I make an IP address can be accessed by visitors like domain name ?. I got information from my server administrator. He told to me, I have to parked my an IP address such as parked a domain name. But I do not know, what is term for that ?.

Indonesia country has blocked many websites such as vimeo.com and other website. Not only that, in my country also blocks "Public DNS" such as Google Public DNS like this https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/ and you definitely know it.

My country is very extreme for blocks a website. You definitely know about my country had very extreme laws or very extreme constitutions such as censor or blur on local TV, porn laws, etc. Almost the same like ISIS laws or other terrorist laws. Maybe parliament in my country has controlled by terrorist or for corruption with many reasons like blocks a website. You definitely know that.

Therefore, many websites use a specifically IP address for visitors to avoid censor. So, visitors do not need PPTP VPN, other VPN or Proxy to unblock a website. They can be directly to a website which is blocked without domain name. But I do not know, what is term for that ?.

Do you know term for that ?.

Answer (score 0):

Colloquially, "numeric IP address".

More technically, "IP address" is always numeric; format like `74.82.164.10` is "dotted decimal IPv4 address", as opposed to, say, hexadecimal IPv6 addresses, or pure decimal, where `74.82.164.10` is equivalent to `1246929930` (here, try it: http://1246929930/).

`berkelilingkesemua.info` is technically not an IP address, as it cannot be used directly in Internet Protocol (IP), but has to be first resolved to a real (numeric) IP address. It is a "fully qualified domain name", or FQDN.

"Parking an IP address" does not make sense to me. "Parking a domain name" is the practice of pointing a domain name to a temporary IP address while you don't have a real server to point it to yet, in order to keep the domain name registered to you while you don't have a real server to point it to. I am not sure how it is related to the other part of your question.

Comment: I do not really understand, but I understand a little bit about IP numeric and FQDN from you. But the point is many websites to avoid censor, they use "Parking an IP address" in cPanel or Webuzo. We can parking an IP address at Add Domain. My server administrator told that step.

Comment: I ask this questions because vimeo.com and reddit.com are blocked by ISP in my country. So, I've been looking for IP address of vimeo.com and reddit.com, but I do not find their IP. If they provide IP for visitors, so I and visitors do not need PPTP VPN, other VPN or Proxy to unblock vimeo.com and reddit.com. I and visitors can be directly to vimeo.com and reddit.com with IP.